# how to use Nlp Pos Tagging in other langauge like sindhi / urdu

Tags: python, nlp, python-requests, stanford-nlp

I am working on a research paper on pos tagging in NLP but my question is that how to implement the pos tagging in another local language plz help me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the POS-Tagger you are using. Usually a (probabilistic) tagger has two language-specific components: a language model and a dictionary.

The dictionary contains all words with their possible tags, annotated by frequency. This can be created and edited manually, or derived from training data. If your language has a rich morphology, you might want to use a morphological analyser to support this, or you could simply have all inflected forms as dictionary entries in their own right.

The language model contains sequences of tags and their frequencies, usually trigrams (sequences of three items). It is extracted from training data, and reflects grammatical constraints on word class distribution.

So in order to adapt an existing tagger for a new language there are two main steps:

1. create a tag set for your language. While there is some overlap between tag sets for different languages (they usually all have nouns or verbs), you might want specific markers for cases or tenses, as they can help in disambiguation.
2. annotate training data. You need some texts to generate the language model (and possibly also the dictionary). This data you feed into the training algorithm to produce the language-specific resource files.

Annotating by hand is fairly tedious, but you can use an iterative process: annotate a smallish text, run it through the training mechanism, and use the tagger to annotate a longer text. This will have many errors, but it's easier to correct the errors than it is to annotate a text from scratch. Then add this text to your training data and repeat. You will find that the tagger's performance will gradually get better as you build up more training data,

Comment: Thanks oliver Mason. And plzzz guide me how these process are work. In English if i can do in english language so i can easily do it my research targeted language. Thank you.

Comment: @TECHNICALHUB That depends on what tagger you're using. They each have their own training procedures; typically that would be described in the documentation.